# How to add AdSense unit in the middle of my blog post on blogger?

Tags: google-adsense, blog, blogger

I am running a blog on blogger. I have been trying to change the XML template code of my blog.
I have tried few methods present on the *following sites*, but it does not work for me.

http://adsinthemiddle.blogspot.com/ and http://djyano.blogspot.com/2008/03/put-your-adsense-in-middle-of-post.html.

Still I'm not able to show AdSense in the middle of my post.

**Edit:**

Finally found a way to do it. Please check the answer.

Comment: I also tried to put my adsense code in the middle of my posts. I've been searching the net for this and found some tutorials.Like you, I followed them but failed on putting the code. It says that the xml cannot be parsed.I hope someone will help us on this.

Comment: actually (for blogger )there is no way to put adsense in the middle of the  post. We can just put them at the starting or ending of the code. You will have to paste the code manually inside each post so that it will appear wherever your want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody finally came up with a [solution](http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2009/12/how-to-put-adsense-ads-inside-your-blog.html). I tweaked code a bit and I could successfully run ads in the middle of post. This solution is for Blogger (blogspot) blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Your site already has at least three AdSense units near the top of the page. Three is the [maximum number of AdSense units that Google allows](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9735) on the entire page.

If you're trying to add a unit to the middle of the page, you might have to remove one or more of the three AdSense units above it, which might be causing it to hit the limit and prevent the fourth unit from displaying.

Comment: @Sangram You might like to add an answer below to say what you did to fix it, then accept it as the solution. It helps others with the same question who may stumble upon this page.